# Input string was not in a correct format using decimal data type

Tags: sql-server, ado, sqldatatypes

when I fill up the form and filled the contact no field then getting an error:

form contactno field:

contactno : 0101001010

**Input string was not in a correct format**

[image]

Database Editor:sql server management studio

table field : **contactno(decimal(18, 0))**

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule: can you do calculations wth a field? No? Then it's not a number; store it as NVarchar/string. Prices, amounts, VAT and discounts, all valid numbers. ID's, zipcodes, phone numbers not so much. What is an ID code + 1000?

In your case, the `contactno` seems to be an ID, not an arithmetic number. You're trying to store the value `0101001010` as a number, but numbers can't have prepended zeroes. This is what generates the `string in invalid input format` error.

The best fix would really be to make this field in the database a text-based column and treat the contact number as text throughout your code.